# Capistrano not pushing binstub to server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano, bundler, capistrano3

I'm running Capistrano 3 in a Rails 4 app, and have a non-bundler binstub in my bin directory (delayed_job). The binstub is checked in to my repository, and I can see it on GitHub. However, when I deploy (using capistrano-bundler), the bin/delayed_job file isn't pushed to the server.

I tried add this to my config/deploy.rb file, but it didn't affect anything:
`set :bundle_bins, fetch(:bundle_bins, []).push('bin/delayed_job')`

Is there something else I need to do to make sure the binstub ends up on the server?

Comment: Update: I tried clearing everything out and redeploying (this time not running Bundler with --binstubs), and now there are *no* binstubs in the bin directory. This makes me think that the bin directory is being ignored by Capistrano, but I can't figure out why.

Comment: what is your deployment strategy? is capistrano checking it out on the server or are you rsyncinc it?

Comment: @phoet Capistrano is checking it out from GitHub.

Comment: have you added bin into linked_dir ? and are using using rvm or rbenv?

Comment: @RahulChaudhari that was it! Can you add it as an answer so you can get the bounty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check if you have added "bin" folder into "linked_dir" call of your Capistrano script.

If you have added then you have to copy file to the server into location your_app/shared/bin/

If not then it will work by check in that file into repository.